# font IranSansX wont work correctly in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm using a font named `IranSansX` which is a popular Persian font. The font rendering is completely correct by default in the Firefox browser. but when I open the website by Google Chrome it has some problems.

#### Firefox

[image: Fonts in firefox browser]

#### Chrome

[image: bad fonts in google chrome]

#### Code

I use vue.js for my frontend and Vuetify as a frontend framework. I didn't write any custom css and everything is default values from the framework.

###### It only breaks when it's inside `<ul><li></li></ul>` tags. Those screenshots was a tags inside a unorderd list as navbar menu

Comment: hi, I used IranSans in my asp program and in my table in browser some columns shows Persian numbers and some of them shows English numbers. Do you have any idea what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `li` tag was `display: inline` which IDK how this causes the bug. But when I changed the `display` property to `inline-block` the problem was not there and fonts renderd correctly.

###### Buggy CSS

```css
ul.nav{
  list-style: none;
  li{
    display: inline;
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fefefe;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: .8rem;
    }
  }
}
```

###### Fixed Version

```css
ul.nav{
  list-style: none;
  li{
    display: inline-block;
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fefefe;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: .8rem;
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone found the real reason that why this happend please comment!